# Flask,Postman and Mysql multiple fields insertion issue

Tags: python, mysql, flask

We are trying to build a prototype for an application using Flask-Postman-Mysql.

Right now we are inserting some data in Postman and that is to be accessed from frontend using Flask and to be stored in Mysql table. Here we are able to insert one field but not multiple fields. 
Here is the postman data:
[image: Data_Insertion_Postman]

Here is the code in Flask for single record insertion:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, make_response
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import jwt
import datetime
from functools import wraps
import mysql.connector

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'thisissecret'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:1234@localhost/flask2018'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Users(db.Model):
    name = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))
@app.route('/users', methods=['POST'])

def create_user():

    data = request.get_json()

    create_user= Users( name=data['name'], password=data['password'])

    db.session.add(create_user)
    db.session.commit()

    return jsonify({'message' : 'New user created!'})

if _name_ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,port=4022)
```

Here is the code in Flask for multiple records:(gives error)

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify,request
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)
mysql = MySQL(app)

# MySQL configurations
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = '1234'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'flask2018'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'

mysql.init_app(app)

@app.route('/users', methods=['POST'])
def get():
    cur = mysql.connect().cursor()
    json_dict = request.get_json()

    name = str(json_dict["name"])
    password = str(json_dict["password"])
    #with cur.cursor() as cursor:
    values = 'INSERT INTO users(name,password) VALUES(%s,%s)'
    cur.execute(values, (name,password))
    mysql.connect().commit()

    #cur.close()

    return jsonify()

if _name_ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,port=4022)
```

When we run the above program some times it shows errors like
1. "Key Name"= 'name'
2. Duplicate Entry 
3. 401 Unauthorized etc

Any suggestions to improve?

Comment: You assigned `name` as primary key field. `name = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)`. Is there any reason behind it.

Comment: No Particular reason,.we just wanted to take any one field as primary key to pass the data.

Comment: So, It will be the problem with `name` field. Please create other field like `id` as Primary Key and `name` as `CharField`. Because as you inserting string data in the `name` field.

Answer (score 4):

I see a couple issues with your implementation.
Your request body has a field `users` and `names` is in the `users` array. That's why you're getting a key error, because you're trying to access `name` even though it's in the field `users` scope.
Another issue is with the definition of the name field in your database schema. You defined it as an integer, but you're passing in a string value.

To get names and passwords, you could do

```
json_dict = request.get_json()
for user in json_dict["users"]:
    name = str(json_dict["name"])
    password = str(json_dict["password"])
```

I imagine you're getting Duplicate Entry fields because you tried posting the same data more than once. Since your primary key is `name` (which I don't recommend), you have to make sure that `name` is not duplicated because you can't insert multiple primary keys that have the same value.

Comment: I implemented your suggestions. Id field is now primary key but while executing it throws an error- Key error:"id" . (our main focus on second program...)

Comment: @RRSS can you give us more detail? How are you inserting id into the db? What data type are you using for it?

Comment: I created a table in Mysql with fields ID (int, primary key ) (n it is auto incremented), name (varchar), password(varchar). I have given input data from POSTMAN as shown in abv image.